# Background-attachment:fixed ? on iphone

Tags: iphone, css

Hey friends How To scroll on iphone.. background-attacment:fixed ? The background picture moving.. but I want stabilize when its scrolling..

I hope you understand me?

Answer (score 0):

Use your view background as an image or add a UIImageView to your view as a subview.
Add a UIScrollView on top of the image view. Whatever elements of the view you want scrollable, should be added as subview to the UIScrollView then.

Comment: I use .net.. no iphone programming

I m talking about My mobil site background-image..

Comment: He probably means CSS for styling purposes in the browser.